# Visual Studio 2022 - Falta la información del código fuente en la información de depuración para este módulo

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, visual-studio-2022

Gente:
Tengo un proyecto que funcionaba bien en VS 2010 pero en 2022 compila (puedo acceder al exe desde bin sin problemas y funciona) me aparece este mensaje de error desde el visual studio y después no me abre la ventana principal del proyecto:

Falta la información del código fuente en la información de depuración para este módulo.

Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste, revisa [ask], saludos.